# Does Kubernetes Ingress Supports Internal Requests?

Tags: kubernetes

Well, there is some question about the Ingress I'm pretty curious about, Does the Kubernetes Ingress support internal requests? For Example what if I want to proxy my requests through the Ingress Between my Microservices?

(The reason, why I'm asking about it, is actually because I want to enable SSL Communication between my Microservices, but don't really want to use Some Kind of. Istio to implement it, so I hope there is some more easier solutions for that :)

Thanks

Comment: you should use a service mesh for this. I.e. linkerd.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes. But realistically, no. Since to have a valid SSL cert that is accepted, you need to somehow verify you own the hostname.

You can't complete the DNS challenge since you don't own the "cluster.local" domain that is used for in-cluster DNS, and the certificate issuers such as Symantec and Entrust won't issue a certificate in that name because again you can't verify you own the domain.

And you can't complete HTTP challenge since "cluster.local" won't route to your specific cluster.

Comment: That's sad.. But Anyways, Is there any methods how to use ssl inside cluster? Probably Setup Some Cert-Manager or Something (but without istio pls :))? I've also heard about traefik DNS Server Implementation, Is it possible to set it up inside Kubernetes cluster and forward requests via it, (Probably sounds mad))

Comment: I guess you could make a self-signed certificate and add the self-signing CA to the nodes (and the clients), but that's pretty hacky

Comment: Sure, and one of the problem is actually about updating them after expiration, so if you got 100 nodes with 100 SSl secrets, that would be fun.

Comment: Exactly. Making something an exception to the norm means having to update it in more places when it does change ^^

Comment: thanks, for response, gonna try to setup my own traefik dns server, so it will probably fulfill my existing needs :P

Comment: Please come back and add an answer of your own when you have done so so everyone can see if it could work for them too.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with Cert-Manager eventually, because it turned out to be most optimal way in comparison with others. [Here is a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoLUigg4V18&t=501s) to a tutorial on Youtube to set it up into your k8s cluster.